# Restlet server using SSL loops indefinitely and produces CPU high load

Tags: ssl, infinite-loop, restlet, peer

I am using Restlet 2.1.2 and 2.2 M3 with Jetty for https (also used Simple Framework). The certificate I am using is signed by Comodo.

I have added both the AddTrust root certificate and the Comodo intermediate certificate to `jre/lib/security/cacerts` (openjdk 7). To be sure they are the correct ones I exported them from Firefox after making a request to the server. I am using cacerts as the truststore and I have another keystore file where I have added the certificate and the private key.

I initially used Firefox, as I mentioned, before making an https request to the server. Firefox gets an answer and the certificate is valid and accepted. The server though, although it has sent the answer, seems that it cannot process the connection properly.

Here is a small portion of the log (debug mode) which I think is interesting:

```
Αυγ 08, 2013 7:38:09 ΜΜ org.restlet.engine.io.Buffer process
FINEST: Draining buffer java.nio.HeapByteBuffer[pos=6 lim=6 cap=16921], DRAINING, true
Αυγ 08, 2013 7:38:09 ΜΜ org.restlet.engine.io.Buffer process
FINEST: Filling buffer java.nio.HeapByteBuffer[pos=0 lim=16921 cap=16921], FILLING, true
Αυγ 08, 2013 7:38:09 ΜΜ org.restlet.ext.ssl.internal.SslConnection setSslResult
FINER: SSL engine result: Status = OK HandshakeStatus = FINISHED
bytesConsumed = 0 bytesProduced = 69
Αυγ 08, 2013 7:38:09 ΜΜ org.restlet.ext.ssl.internal.SslConnection setSslResult
FINER: SSL connection: OPEN | true | Interest= READ , Ready=READ , Canceling=false | 1d7f705[SSLEngine[hostname=null port=-1] TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA] | Status = BUFFER_OVERFLOW HandshakeStatus = NEED_WRAP
bytesConsumed = 0 bytesProduced = 0
Αυγ 08, 2013 7:38:09 ΜΜ org.restlet.engine.io.Buffer process
FINEST: 69 bytes filled into buffer
Αυγ 08, 2013 7:38:09 ΜΜ org.restlet.engine.io.Buffer process
FINEST: Filling buffer java.nio.HeapByteBuffer[pos=69 lim=16921 cap=16921], FILLING, false
Αυγ 08, 2013 7:38:09 ΜΜ org.restlet.engine.io.Buffer process
FINEST: Draining buffer java.nio.HeapByteBuffer[pos=0 lim=69 cap=16921], DRAINING, false
Αυγ 08, 2013 7:38:09 ΜΜ org.restlet.engine.io.Buffer process
FINEST: 69 bytes drained from buffer, 0 remaining bytes
Αυγ 08, 2013 7:38:09 ΜΜ org.restlet.engine.io.Buffer process
FINEST: Draining buffer java.nio.HeapByteBuffer[pos=69 lim=69 cap=16921], DRAINING, true
Αυγ 08, 2013 7:38:09 ΜΜ org.restlet.engine.io.Buffer process
FINEST: Filling buffer java.nio.HeapByteBuffer[pos=0 lim=16921 cap=16921], FILLING, true
Αυγ 08, 2013 7:38:09 ΜΜ org.restlet.engine.io.Buffer process
FINEST: Ending process of buffer java.nio.HeapByteBuffer[pos=0 lim=16921 cap=16921], FILLING, true. Result: 75, try again: false, can loop: true, total filled: 75
Αυγ 08, 2013 7:38:09 ΜΜ org.restlet.ext.ssl.internal.SslConnection handleSslResult
FINER: Handling SSL result: OK
Αυγ 08, 2013 7:38:09 ΜΜ org.restlet.ext.ssl.internal.SslConnection handleSslHandshake
FINER: Handling SSL handshake: FINISHED
Αυγ 08, 2013 7:38:09 ΜΜ org.restlet.engine.connector.Way setIoState
FINER: InboundWay#setIoState: INTEREST
Αυγ 08, 2013 7:38:09 ΜΜ org.restlet.engine.connector.Way setIoState
FINER: OutboundWay#setIoState: IDLE
Αυγ 08, 2013 7:38:09 ΜΜ org.restlet.engine.connector.OutboundWay onDrain
FINER: 75 bytes written
Αυγ 08, 2013 7:38:09 ΜΜ org.restlet.engine.io.Buffer process
FINEST: 75 bytes drained from buffer at pre-processing, 0 remaining bytes
Αυγ 08, 2013 7:38:09 ΜΜ org.restlet.engine.io.Buffer process
FINEST: Ending process of buffer java.nio.HeapByteBuffer[pos=0 lim=0 cap=16916], DRAINING, true. Result: 75, try again: true, can loop: false, total filled: 0
Αυγ 08, 2013 7:38:09 ΜΜ org.restlet.ext.ssl.internal.SslConnection handleSslResult
FINER: Handling SSL result: OK
Αυγ 08, 2013 7:38:09 ΜΜ org.restlet.ext.ssl.internal.SslConnection handleSslHandshake
FINER: Handling SSL handshake: NOT_HANDSHAKING
Αυγ 08, 2013 7:38:09 ΜΜ org.restlet.engine.connector.Way onSelected
FINER: Outbound way selected. Done for : IDLE, IDLE, java.nio.HeapByteBuffer[pos=0 lim=0 cap=16916], DRAINING, true
Αυγ 08, 2013 7:38:09 ΜΜ org.restlet.engine.connector.ConnectionController doRun
FINEST: helper.control()
Αυγ 08, 2013 7:38:09 ΜΜ org.restlet.engine.connector.ConnectionController doRun
FINEST: controlConnections()
Αυγ 08, 2013 7:38:09 ΜΜ org.restlet.engine.connector.ConnectionController controlConnection
FINEST: Connection status: OPEN | true | Interest= READ , Ready=NONE , Canceling=false | f4af1e[SSLEngine[hostname=null port=-1] TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA] | null
Αυγ 08, 2013 7:38:09 ΜΜ org.restlet.engine.connector.ConnectionController controlConnection
FINEST: Connection status: OPEN | true | Interest= READ , Ready=READ , Canceling=false | 1d7f705[SSLEngine[hostname=null port=-1] TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA] | null
Αυγ 08, 2013 7:38:09 ΜΜ org.restlet.engine.connector.Connection updateState
FINEST: Old connection NIO interest: Interest= READ , Ready=READ , Canceling=false
Αυγ 08, 2013 7:38:09 ΜΜ org.restlet.engine.connector.Connection updateState
FINEST: New connection NIO interest: Interest= READ , Ready=NONE , Canceling=false
Αυγ 08, 2013 7:38:09 ΜΜ org.restlet.engine.connector.ConnectionController doRun
FINEST: registerKeys()
Αυγ 08, 2013 7:38:09 ΜΜ org.restlet.engine.connector.ConnectionController doRun
FINEST: updateKeys()
Αυγ 08, 2013 7:38:09 ΜΜ org.restlet.engine.connector.ConnectionController doRun
FINEST: selectKeys(60000)
Αυγ 08, 2013 7:38:09 ΜΜ org.restlet.engine.connector.ConnectionController selectKeys
FINER: NIO controller about to sleep 60000 ms, selecting among 3 keys...
Αυγ 08, 2013 7:38:09 ΜΜ org.restlet.engine.connector.ConnectionController selectKeys
FINER: NIO controller selected 1 key(s) !
Αυγ 08, 2013 7:38:09 ΜΜ org.restlet.engine.connector.ConnectionController onSelected
FINEST: NIO selection detected for key: Interest= READ , Ready=NONE , Canceling=false
```

And after some more lines, it throws the well known exception:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: peer not authenticated
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSessionImpl.getPeerCertificates(SSLSessionImpl.java:397)
        at org.restlet.ext.ssl.internal.SslConnection.getSslClientCertificates(SslConnection.java:186)
        at org.restlet.ext.ssl.internal.HttpsInboundRequest.<init>(HttpsInboundRequest.java:71)
        at org.restlet.ext.ssl.HttpsServerHelper.createRequest(HttpsServerHelper.java:129)
        at org.restlet.engine.connector.ServerInboundWay.readStartLine(ServerInboundWay.java:208)
        at org.restlet.engine.connector.InboundWay.onDrain(InboundWay.java:249)
        at org.restlet.engine.io.Buffer.process(Buffer.java:557)
        at org.restlet.engine.connector.Way.processIoBuffer(Way.java:503)
        at org.restlet.engine.connector.InboundWay.processIoBuffer(InboundWay.java:360)
        at org.restlet.engine.connector.Way.onSelected(Way.java:456)
        at org.restlet.util.SelectionRegistration.onSelected(SelectionRegistration.java:325)
        at org.restlet.engine.connector.Connection.onSelected(Connection.java:612)
        at org.restlet.util.SelectionRegistration.onSelected(SelectionRegistration.java:325)
        at org.restlet.engine.connector.ConnectionController.onSelected(ConnectionController.java:219)
        at org.restlet.engine.connector.ServerConnectionController.onSelected(ServerConnectionController.java:99)
        at org.restlet.engine.connector.ConnectionController.selectKeys(ConnectionController.java:308)
        at org.restlet.engine.connector.ConnectionController.doRun(ConnectionController.java:171)
        at org.restlet.engine.connector.Controller.run(Controller.java:159)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

And the server seems to continue doing work with several log lines like this one:
FINER: Handling SSL handshake: NOT_HANDSHAKING

After that, I tried to connect from a passbook iphone app (this aims to be a passbook web service) and the server seems to enter a loop from which it cannot get out.

Here are some log lines:

```
Αυγ 08, 2013 7:50:56 ΜΜ org.restlet.engine.io.Buffer process
FINEST: Ending process of buffer java.nio.HeapByteBuffer[pos=0 lim=16921 cap=16921], FILLING, true. Result: -1, try again: false, can loop: true, total filled: 0
Αυγ 08, 2013 7:50:56 ΜΜ org.restlet.ext.ssl.internal.SslConnection handleSslResult
FINER: Handling SSL result: CLOSED
Αυγ 08, 2013 7:50:56 ΜΜ org.restlet.engine.connector.Connection close
FINER: Closing connection to /83.235.173.2:19708 gracefully
Αυγ 08, 2013 7:50:56 ΜΜ org.restlet.engine.connector.OutboundWay onDrain
FINER: -1 bytes written
Αυγ 08, 2013 7:50:56 ΜΜ org.restlet.engine.io.Buffer process
FINEST: -1 bytes drained from buffer at pre-processing, 0 remaining bytes
Αυγ 08, 2013 7:50:56 ΜΜ org.restlet.engine.io.Buffer process
FINEST: Draining buffer java.nio.HeapByteBuffer[pos=0 lim=0 cap=16916], DRAINING, true
Αυγ 08, 2013 7:50:56 ΜΜ org.restlet.engine.io.Buffer process
FINEST: Filling buffer java.nio.HeapByteBuffer[pos=0 lim=16916 cap=16916], FILLING, true
Αυγ 08, 2013 7:50:56 ΜΜ org.restlet.engine.io.Buffer process
FINEST: Ending process of buffer java.nio.HeapByteBuffer[pos=0 lim=16916 cap=16916], FILLING, true. Result: -1, try again: false, can loop: true, total filled: 0
Αυγ 08, 2013 7:50:56 ΜΜ org.restlet.ext.ssl.internal.SslConnection handleSslResult
FINER: Handling SSL result: OK
Αυγ 08, 2013 7:50:56 ΜΜ org.restlet.ext.ssl.internal.SslConnection handleSslHandshake
FINER: Handling SSL handshake: NOT_HANDSHAKING
Αυγ 08, 2013 7:50:56 ΜΜ org.restlet.engine.connector.Way onSelected
FINER: Outbound way selected. Done for : READY, IDLE, java.nio.HeapByteBuffer[pos=0 lim=16916 cap=16916], FILLING, true
Αυγ 08, 2013 7:50:56 ΜΜ org.restlet.engine.connector.Connection onSelected
FINEST: Entering into a connection READY loop
Αυγ 08, 2013 7:50:56 ΜΜ org.restlet.engine.connector.Way onSelected
FINER: Processing IO for outbound way: READY, IDLE, java.nio.HeapByteBuffer[pos=0 lim=16916 cap=16916], FILLING, true
Αυγ 08, 2013 7:50:56 ΜΜ org.restlet.engine.io.Buffer process
FINEST: Beginning process of buffer java.nio.HeapByteBuffer[pos=0 lim=16916 cap=16916], FILLING, true
Αυγ 08, 2013 7:50:56 ΜΜ org.restlet.engine.io.Buffer process
FINEST: Beginning process of buffer java.nio.HeapByteBuffer[pos=0 lim=16921 cap=16921], FILLING, true
Αυγ 08, 2013 7:50:56 ΜΜ org.restlet.engine.io.Buffer process
FINEST: 0 bytes drained from buffer at pre-processing, 16921 remaining bytes
Αυγ 08, 2013 7:50:56 ΜΜ org.restlet.engine.io.Buffer process
FINEST: Filling buffer java.nio.HeapByteBuffer[pos=0 lim=16921 cap=16921], FILLING, true
Αυγ 08, 2013 7:50:56 ΜΜ org.restlet.ext.ssl.internal.SslConnection setSslResult
FINER: SSL engine result: Status = CLOSED HandshakeStatus = NOT_HANDSHAKING
```

and this loop seems to be endless. Also, CPU load reaches 100%.

Comment: Have you tried to use a different connector? (Note that there is no point adding the certificates to `cacerts` unless you want to use client-certificate authentication.)

Comment: I have also tried Simple Framework with the exact same behavior. I didn't know that about cacerts. I just thought I should try it.